# What allocing return values are allowed?

Tags: c, malloc, language-lawyer

Which of these functions may return 1?

Allocating and freeing suddenly stop working

```
int foo1(size_t a) {
    void *t = malloc(a);
    if (t == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (1) {
        free(t);
        t = malloc(a);
        if (t == NULL)
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Fail to realloc but succeed to malloc

```
int foo2(size_t a, size_t b) {
    void *t = malloc(a);
    if (realloc(t, b))
        return 0;
    if (malloc(b))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Neither a new allocing nor a pure expand

```
int foo3(size_t a, size_t b) {
    void *p, *q;
    p = malloc(a);
    if (malloc(b))
        return 0;
    q = realloc(p, b);
    return p != q && q;
}
```

Comment: "Fail to realloc" - you have to assign the returned pointer, or you lose the allocation.

Comment: On which platform?

Comment: What is the point here? All of these can conceivably fail (the standard gives no guarantees whatsoever), and the existence of other threads and processes makes allocation failures technically possible every time. So what's your real problem?

Comment: In the first function you return both `0` and `1` for a `malloc` failure. What are you trying to do anyway? Break your resources?

Comment: well, someone shows his implement to `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`, where `malloc` gives a new block, `realloc` always fail unless old pointer is zero, and `free` does nothing. Not sure if it fits the standard on behave

Comment: So is the question about someone's own implementation of `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`? Sending a `NULL` pointer to `realloc` is of no help, the original block can be neither extended or replaced, so there will be a memory leak.

Comment: @WeatherVane kind of but further

Comment: Sometimes these things can fail from memory fragmentation when repeatedly allocating and freeing memory, so there ends up without a large enough contiguous block of memory available.

Comment: If this is test code for a heap manager, you've got a long way to go. I would start by learning a programming language, might as well be C, then learn how write algorithms and practice converting those to C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the fact that you did not include `<stdlib.h>`, there is no compelling reason for `foo1` to eventually fail and return `1`. Termination of this function for any given value of `a` is implementation specific. Most systems will eventually recycle the freed block and never fail to reallocate `a` bytes, but a system where `free` does nothing is still Standard compliant, and the loop may eventually fail.

Function `foo2` causes one or more memory leaks. It would return `1` if `realloc()` fails but `malloc()` for the same size succeeds.  While such a case would be surprising, there is no guaranty that failure to reallocate a block (or `NULL` is `malloc(a)` failed) implies that the next call to `malloc()` with the same size should fail too.

Function `foo3` has potential undefined behavior: you should not use the value of `p` after `q = realloc(p, b)`. If the block was indeed reallocated, the value of `p` can become a trap value, so it should not be compared to anything.  You could work around this by storing the value of `p` into an `unsigned char` array and compare the byte values after the call to `realloc`. Yet the comparison may should differences even if the block was not moved. There does not seems to be a portable method to determine if `realloc()` moved the block or not.

Nevertheless, on systems where `p` does not become a trap value, it is indeed possible that `malloc(b)` fail and `realloc(p, b)` succeed and return a different address: If the memory heap does not have an available block for `malloc(b)`, `malloc` will return `NULL`, but if there is free space before `p` that can be coalesced to form a block of size `b`, `realloc` may succeed and return a different address.

All these tests have implementation defined behavior.